# Any efficient way for batch backup of all tables in a DolphinDB database?

Tags: database-administration, database-backups, dolphindb

I am looking for a more efficient way of backing up the data into the database. Is there any suggested function or method of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following to achieve batch backups:

```
backupDir="E:/Tools/DB_backup"
def batchBackup(backupDir){
    for(db in getDFSDatabase){
        tableList = getTables(database(db));
        for(table in tableList){
            backup(backupDir, <select * from loadTable(db, table)>, true);
        }
    }
}
batchBackup(backupDir);
```

If you are interested, here is the complete script for validation.

```
login(`admin, `123456)
backupDir="E:/Tools/DB_backup

n = 10
t1=table(rand(2012.12.01..2012.12.10, n) as date, rand(`AAPL`IBM`MSFT`GOOG, n) as sym, rand(1000.0, n) as price)
t2=table(rand(2012.12.01..2012.12.10, n) as date, rand(`AAPL`IBM`MSFT`GOOG, n) as sym, rand(1000, n) as qty)
db1 = database("dfs://db2", VALUE, `AAPL`IBM`MSFT`GOOG)
quotes1 = db1.createPartionedTable(t1, `quotes1, `sym).append!(t1)
quotes2 = db2.createPartionedTable(t2, `quotes2, `sym).append!(t2)
// one-by-one backup
backup(backupDir, <select * from trades1>, true)
backup(backupDir, <select * from trades2>, true)
backup(backupDir, <select * from quotes1>, true)
backup(backupDir, <select * from quotes2>, true)

dropDatabase("dfs://db1")
dropDatabase("dfs://db2")

select * from loadTable("dfs://db1", `trades1);

// batch recovery
migrate(backupDir);
backupDir="E:/Tools/DB_backup"
def batchBackup(backupDir){
    for(db in getDFSDatabses()){
        tableList = getTables(database(db));
        for(table in tableList){
            backup(backupDir, <select * from loadTable(db, table)>, false);
        }
    }
}
// batch backup
batchBackup(backupDir);
select * from loadTable("dfs://db1", `trade1);
```